# Having a problem with a function in my C program. Program terminates before executing the second last "printf()" in the "encript()" function

Tags: c, function, char

When I call "encript()", it works how I want it to until the second last "printf()" at which point the program terminates without executing any more lines. I tried searching for similar questions here and tried to fix my code but nothing that I could find seemed to work.
I am a beginner so please forgive me if it's just a simple mistake.

```
char encript(int x){
    printf("You selected Encription with the key: %d\n\n", x);  //Tells user the key value they input
    Sleep(1000);
    int msglength = 100;  //Variable for the amount of characters in the messge
    printf("\n\nEnter aproximate number of characters in you message. \nThe number must be at least 1 over the amount of characters in your message: ");
    scanf("%d", msglength);    //assigns user input integer to msglength
    printf("\n\n");
    char message[msglength];    //Creates a character array for the message with a length of "msglength"
    printf("Insert message here: ");    ////THIS LINE DOES NOT SEEM TO EXECUTE. NOR DO THE TWO BELOW IT.
    scanf("%s", message);
    printf("\n\n%s", message);
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did run your code in a **debugger** to see where that error occurs, then run it again with a breakpoint near that failure so you can step carefully ahead and watch what happens leading up to that point?

Comment: Are you compiling with full warnings enabled (`-Wall` in some compilers) to make sure you're calling the functions correctly?

Comment: Also: "encrypt" is probably what you mean.

Comment: `scanf("%d", &msglength);` - scanf requires addresses of variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pay attention to this line `scanf("%d", msglength);` , for scanning variables you should send their address to `scnaf` , so this should be `scanf("%d", &msglength);`(add `&` to `scanf`)

this function should `return` a character ,if you just want to to `scan` a message and `print` it , you should use `void` like this  `void encript(int x)` also if you want to return message  you can use `char * encript(int x)` .

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it fixed the problem.  Don't know how I missed that.    As for the char vs void, I want to return the encrypted message back into main() so that means I need "char" right? What difference does "char * " make vs "char " and do i need the asterisk? Thanks again.

Comment: @CheeseMellon message is an array of character so you need this `char *` but  `char` is for one character like `a` ,`b`,...